# Iterate through text stream that isn't full yet

Tags: python

I have the following, functioning code to output real-time subprocess stdout data.

```
import subprocess

ps = subprocess.Popen(
   'ls && sleep 5 && ls',
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True,
    encoding='utf-8'
)

for item in ps.stdout:
    if item:
        print(item)
    else:
        break

print('process has terminated')
```

This will print the result of `ls`, wait five seconds, and then print the results of `ls` again.

**What I don't understand is why `for item in ps.stdout` is working in this way**. I would think that it would print the results of the first `ls`, then reach the end of `stdout`, and print the final `process has terminated`.

My best guess is it has something to do with iterable/generator/stream behavior? Insight is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` will continue until it receives an "end" signal from the iterator.  `stdout` is the delivery end of an active pipe; as long as that pipe is open, there is no "end" signal.  The `for` will wait for further responses from the pipe; this is how a pipe works.

If a pipe did *not* work this way, the receiving end would need to develop asynchronous communication with the subprocess, to know whether any more data was expected.